# Size of function spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions

For example, how big is the space $ C^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) $ ? How much is, say, $ C^0  $ larger than $ C^1$ ? How can one figure out ?

Comment: I think that this is a beautiful question.  Any complete answer should certainly reference Liouville's famous theorem about certain functions, such as $\sin(x)/x$ and $e^{x^2}$, whose antiderivatives cannot be expressed in closed form in terms of simple functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking about cardinality, it turns out they both have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. For $\mathbb{R}^2$ this has been proven many ways. An overkill approach is to use space-filling curves.

For $C^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, here's a sketch of a proof based on the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem. Verifying one half of the hypotheses of the theorem is easy: $|C^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$ because we have an injective function $f : \mathbb{R} \to C^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(x) = y \mapsto x$. In other words, $f$ maps each real number to the corresponding constant function, which is certainly smooth.

The other half is harder. First we certainly have that $|C^k(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})| \leq |C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})|$ because we have an inclusion map.

Showing that $|C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$ is the hard part. The idea of the proof is to show that a continuous function is uniquely defined by its values on $\mathbb{Q}$. In other words, there is an injection $g : C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is given by the restriction map. So $|C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})| \leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}| = |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}|$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable).

This last cardinality is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}$. There is a direct proof based on an interlacing argument, similar to how one usually proves that $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}|$. An "algebraic" proof is:

$$\left | \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \right | = \left | (2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}} \right | = \left | 2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \right | = \left | 2^{\mathbb{N}} \right | = \left | \mathbb{R} \right |.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it means that we can map each function to a real number?
What if we change the domain and the range? Is there in general some kind of relation between the cardinality of the function space and that of the domain/range?

Comment: @ToChinYu Not really. For one thing, the set of *all* functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has a larger cardinality than the set of continuous functions. (A proof like my last one: $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|=|(2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{R}}| = |2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}}| = |2^{\mathbb{R}}|$. This is larger than $|\mathbb{R}|$ by Cantor's theorem.) So the cardinality is related to the continuity restriction. "Typically" a function space has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't say what exactly "typically" means.

Comment: Ops, by function I meant function in the said function space. So we can map each continuous function to a real number then? I just find that a little mind-bending.

Comment: @ToChinYu Yes, you can map each continuous function to a real number. But the construction of the bijection is rather complicated, considerably more complicated than the construction of the injections separately.

Answer (score 2):

There are many senses of bigger; here's one that gives an easy, concrete answer: As a vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual notions of addition and scalar multiplication, $C^k(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ is infinite-dimensional, whereas $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension two.

Comment: Ok, I guess there is not much of a point to compare it to the real plane then. I have edited my question, hopefully it would make my concern clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, btw. =)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

A quite related question: How small is $C^{k+1}([0,1])$ inside $C^{k}([0,1])$. Note that $C^{k}$ is a Banach space with a norm say $\sum_{l=o}^k \sum\sup_t||f^{l}(t)||$. It turns out that $C^{k+1}$ is of first category in $C^{k}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set), a classic result.